# *Edit* Service Fabric - Can't Debug With .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net, azure-service-fabric

Now that I have figured out what is going on (can't debug services using .NET 6 in Service Fabric), does anyone have an idea of how to get this to work? Some setting in VS, or just a limitation of support from Service Fabric?

I have a collection of service fabric services all hosted in a local cluster. As of a few days ago, I lost the ability to step into those when I attach to the various processes. For the life of me I don't see what has changed in any of my settings, projects, etc.

Since it happened I have tried a number of things.

1. Multiple reboots.
2. Launch the debugger directly from a service method (it gets called and debugger window launches, but nothing to debug due to the "application in break mode" issue).
3. Have updated to latest SF packages (and runtime).
4. Torn down and restart my local cluster.

I can debug into unit tests and other code just fine, seems something odd is going on with the SF side of things.

Has anyone else experienced this behavior and can offer some insight?

**Edit 5/9/22** Since my post I have also done the following.

1. Reset all settings back to default in VS 2022
2. Updated to VS 17.1.6
3. Update local SF runtime to 9.0.1017 (also updated all SF nuget packages to latest version)
4. Removed certs and reverted to an unsecured local cluster
5. Went back to an OLD version of the code (one I know was debuggable) to see if it was a change I made

**Edit 5/11/22** Found the culprit.
Seems to be that even though Service Fabric now supports .NET 6, there is something broken with respect to debugging it. If I revert back to a version of my code using .NET 5, I can once again debug on the fabric. If all I do then is update the project to .NET 6, debugging goes away. Curious.

Comment: Well, I made some rather random and arbitrary changes to the service and for some unexplainable (by me) reason, I was eventually promoted with a "Step into" message box and then I was mysteriously able to debug these by attaching to their process again. I would really like to know what the trigger is - for when it happens again...

Comment: And the problem has mysteriously reappeared...

Comment: We have the same problem. It will break if you start the application in visual studio. However, if you do a publish and attach to the process, we get the break mode screen. no solution yet

Comment: Additional info, it only happens with remoting services. i can attach to asp.net services fine.  I also see when I attach the debugger output has : Failed to load metadata for 'nameofdllcontainingserviceinterface.service.mt', possibly because the process is corrupt.

Comment: more info, remoting V1 works. so it's something to do with remoting V2,V2_1

Comment: user2202761 yes, I see the same output messages.

Comment: I have added a bug report to the SF project github. https://github.com/microsoft/service-fabric/issues/1356